# UItableViewCell - don't allow to select the cell, but can still press buttons inside it?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can you add a button as a subview to a uitableview cell and have that clickable, but not the cell itself. ie: I don't want the selected view to come up. Obvs I can just not have the cell disclose anywhere, but I don't want it to look "selected" when someone taps it.

Setting user interaction enabled to NO makes the whole thing unenabled, including the buttons.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Tom

Answer (score 15, accepted):

implement this delegate method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return nil;
}
```

and set the UITableViewCells selectionStyle property to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone

Answer (score 21):

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

This will prevent the cell to highlight for a bit before the willSelect returns nil

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, by setting the `selectionStyle` in this way the cell doesn't respond to any taps at all. By using the method in the chosen answer the cell will still flash its selected state (darker background) for a split second.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the option "no selection" on the attributes inspector like in the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or you could uncheck the user interaction in the Attributes inspector of the cell interface file.
Localice the section: "View" and the subtitle: "Interaction", here you have: "User Interaction Enabled".